# How are uninstalls recorded on Google Play console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I want to know how uninstalls on my app are recorded on the Google Play console exactly. I do not want my own personal uninstalls on my test devices to show, so I want to find out how the uninstalls work, in order to block them.

When testing an app on Android Studio over and over are those updates/uninstalls recorded on the Google Play console? If I install the app using an external APK and not through the store, do uninstalls of those get recorded?

Thanks.

P.S. I have tried googling this question but the problem is I could not find any relevant answers. Three hours after searching and still cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I have not been able to find exact documentation of your problem but you don't need to worry as it is sure that Google will not count installs or uninstall of your debug/signed apk if you install it manually or from Android studio.

It counts the number of installs or uninstalls of your application only if you download the app from Google Play Store.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot detect the uninstall event of your own app. When an app is uninstalled the event `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` is sent as a broadcast to all apps except the app which is being uninstalled.

So to answer your question, Google console calculates the number of uninstalls via Google Play Store app, not via your own app.

Also, Google Play store only tracks the install and uninstall events for the apps which are installed from the Play store. So, if you want to block the uninstalls from your test devices from being counted, install the APK directly and not from the play store.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Sorry I could not upvote and I had to select only one answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recently google changed the way of calculations, so you can find [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9419939?hl=en) how it's performing.