# Do google count uninstall if i uninstall my application installed from the andriod studio

Tags: android, store, playback

If i have uploaded the application on play store , i am working on it and uninstall it many times that installed by android studio every time i run the application, will the google count its uninstall in play store ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530837/how-are-uninstalls-recorded-on-google-play-console/51531001

Comment: No, it only counts the installs and uninstalls made from the Play Store - the debug app is actually considered as a different app by the system, because of the different signing key, so you can even have both the app from the store and the debug one on your device in the same time.

Comment: Maybe I have not been able to find exact documentation of your problem but you don't need to worry as it is sure that Google will not count installs or uninstall of your debug/signed apk if you install it manually or from Android studio.

It counts the number of installs or uninstalls of your application only if you download the app from Google Play Store.




thanks for this help